# how to change object type into integer type?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset that the column is about duration time, e.g. 90 mins, 87, min, 107 mins, etc.
What the best method to change this object type into integer type? so i know how to calculate the mean, mode, median, etc

Answer (score 0):

From your question I dont know if you have '90' or '90 min' inside your cell.
If you have 90 min you first have to remove the string component 'min', then you have to convert the type of the column:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' min', ''))
df = df.astype({'column_name':'int'})
```

Comment: i have '90 min' each row. I have to split them first maybe. So i will have two columns. But i dont know how to remove 'min'

Comment: here you go @HandriMauludinMaulana, but your question has been asked many times (as pointed out by admins), so next time try to spend more time searching for your solution